# Recursive formula for a combinatorial problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion, combinatorics-on-words

***Question:***

> Let $\Sigma =\{1,2,3,4\}$. For $n\ge 1,$ let $S_n$ be the set of all words above $\Sigma$ in which each adjacent chars are different and the last char isn't the same as the first char. E.g.: $3231234\in S_7$. Let $y_n=|S_n|$. Find the recursive function with starting conditions for $y_n$.

---

$Solution.$ we shall take all calculations around the third char of the string since it is possible to take a smaller string to satisfy the conditions from there.

1. If the third char is as the last: then the second char is different from the last, therefore, we have: $y_{n-1}$.
2. If the third char isn't equal to the last: then we can take the sub-word starting with the third char and for that: $3\cdot y_{n-2}$.

In total, $$y_n=y_{n-1}+3y_{n-2},y_1=4,y_2=12$$

---

I don't know if the solution is correct. I will be glad if you show me how to approach such questions. Thanks!

Comment: Well, why not test your formula?  You say that $y_3=12+3\times 4=24$.  Does that seem sensible to you?  Work out the case of $3$ character strings by hand and check.

Comment: @lulu You're right, for $y_4$ it isn't true, so what have I done wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your calculation.    I suggest:  Ignore the bit about the last character.  Solve the problem then.  Then split the cases into those which pass your last character test and those that don't.

Comment: @lulu can you show me what you mean? because I was trying a lot of things.

Comment: Ok.  Suppose you ignore the restriction on the last character.  What's the count then?  {this bit is easy).

Comment: When I don't have a restriction about the last char, then I pick a valid sequence of length n-1 and attach a first char which has 3 options. So we get: $3y_{n-1}$ right?

Comment: So, what's the answer?  In closed form.

Comment: @lulu $y_n=3y_{n-1}$ I believe?

Comment: @lulu is it because when I take a valid sequence with a length of $n-1$ the second char is always different from the first, so we satisfy the condition of the first char being different from the last?

Comment: That's a recursion.  i want closed form.  A simple numerical function of $n$.  Really, this is not hard.  (your recursion is right, by the way).

Comment: @lulu You are right. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: If you like, you can post your own solution below.  I'll review it once you do.

Comment: @lulu If you can I will be glad that you will post a formal one, just to see how you right it. thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, no.  I'll work with you towards an answer but I won't do the work for you.

Comment: @lulu understood and respect that!

Comment: @lulu **[and to the OP]** Thanks for the assist.  You are absolutely right, my analysis was bad.  I have therefore deleted my answer.  I simply didn't examine the OP's illustrating cases closely enough.  That is, the OP considers 3231234 to be a *good* sequence.

Comment: @user2661923 everything is good, I have understood how to solve this. Thanks for your time :)